# Finding solution to $(f/g)'=\lambda(f'/g)$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}^*$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, $\lambda=u/v \in \mathbb{Q}^*=\mathbb{Q}-\{0\}$,
and let $f=f(x)$ and $g=g(x)$ be two polynomials in one variable $x$ over $k$.

**My question:** What is the solution to $(f/g)'=\lambda (f'/g)$?

Is there a shorter way to find it then writing $f=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix^i$
and $g= \sum_{i=1}^{m}b_ix^i$, where $a_i ,b_i \in k$, $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$,
and using the formula for the derivative of a quotient?

Actually, I originally wished to solve $(v-u)f'g-vfg'=0$, which is equivalent to
$(f/g)'=\lambda (f'/g)= (u/v) (f'/g)$.
I do not yet have a solution, only some necessary conditions, for example,
$(v-u)n=vm$.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Hint: try taking the derivative of $\frac{f^{v-u}}{g^v}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to work as if
these are standard functions
in real variables.

If
$(f/g)'=c (f'/g)
$,
then
$c\dfrac{f'}{g}
=\dfrac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}
$
or
$cf'g
=f'g-fg'
$
or
$fg' = (1-c)f'g
$.

If
$c=1$
then
$fg' = 0$,
so one of these are zero.
If $f=0$ then both sides are zero.
If $g'=0$ then $g$ is constant
which makes the equation trivially true.

If $c \ne 1$,
and we are just interested
in power seriessolutions,
we could substitute power series
for $f$ and $g$
into
$fg' = (1-c)f'g
$
and get a recursion for
the coefficients of
$f$ or $g$
in terms of the other.

We could also rewrite the equation as
$\dfrac{g'}{g}
=(1-c)\dfrac{f'}{f}
$
or
$(\ln g)'
=(1-c)(\ln f)'$.

Integrating.
$\ln g = (1-c)\ln f + k
$
or
$g = e^k f^{1-c}
$
so that
$f 
= (e^{-k}g)^{1/(1-c)}
= e^{-kb}g^b
$
where
$b = 1/(1-c)$.

Comment: And of course the $e^{-kb}$ is just a not-so-scary constant, and so to get the answer for polynomials we can raise both sides to the $v-u$ power to get a polynomial equation on both sides.